# List of Ticket Management Software

Tags: continuous-delivery, build-pipeline, capacity-planning, practices

My devops team is struggling with managing incidents and having quick response times anyone know of some software that can help with this?

And the pros and cons of them?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because list doesn't work well on StackExchange format and tend to get outdated pretty quickly. Moreover everyone will have its favorite system and after 12 answers you won't be more helped to choose.

Answer (score 2):

Currently my team uses Jira, and it's RapidBoard agile thing.  We aren't using real agile, but it's nice to schedule work loads for the next week.

Jira can be super complex, but we Have our tickets set up to:

```
New -->InProgress -->Done
     +-> Won't Do
```

It can be linked to github or to Bitstream, etc.  which is nice.  If you want more complex code reviews, Atlassian also has a code review tool (Crucible) that I really liked (used it at my previous job).

The real trick is to have the ability to schedule things and to track what state they are in.

The hardest part for us was to get people to break up large projects into multiple smaller tickets to better track progress.

Answer (score -1):

Hey you should check out ngDesk. It does ticket and on-call/pager management, its also completely free.

Its a really awesome tool that my team has been using and loves.

Here is the link https://www.ngdesk.com